# Best javascript graph for a scaling timeline..

Tags: php, javascript, graph

I'm open to php graphing frameworks aswel, or anything that can output a .png with a nice transparent canvas background.

Anyway the data I have is like

```
-Time in format:: 25/11/12 - 11:20:01 PM +0000  
-Total Players online:: 29  
-And a list of player names:: Player1, Player2, Player3
```

For the time format I could convert to epoch if it would make things a lot easy to graph?

I've seen some graphs where you can zoom in and out on a time line.. As I've got results taken every 5mins that's about 288 results for a 24hr period. So just looking for something that would be fairly easy to setup.

The extra fancything I was wondering was, if on mouseOver a particular result, it could show player names on at that time?

So anyone familiar with all the different javascript graphing scripts know of one that would easily do this without to much extra scripting on my side seeing i'm not fluent with javascript much at all.

Comment: Have you considered Google Charts?  https://developers.google.com/chart/  You can export to a png though the feature is deprecated.

Comment: I haven't considered them, I'm really wanting the script library to either be on the localsite or within the sent page as embedded script, don't like google analytics or googleapis or sites full of third party scripts... don't like google full stop actually... as a last resort though I'll take a look at the charts just incase it fits the bill easier than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascript:**

Try [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) - A good library which I've used recently as it's got a lot of functionality and is highly flexible/configurable.

You could also try [Rgraph](http://www.rgraph.net) too, which is an HTML5 charting library written in Javascript and that uses the HTML5 `canvas` tag to render/draw.

**PHP:**

[JpGraph](http://www.jpgraph.net) is a solid PHP-driven charting library that has been around for years and has been continually improved.